# Laravel polymorphic relationship 0 results

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic relationship with Laravel. 
My polymorphic relationship is Message->messageable becoming either Group or Chat.

Going from Message->messageable will give me the proper result(e.g the group or chat the message is associated with).

Going from example Group::first()->with('messages')->get() will return an empty messages array.

My db tables for message are
messageable_id
messageable_type

My model methods are as follows

```
class Message extends Model
{
public function messageable(){
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

^works as intended

```
class Group extends Model
{
function messages(){
    return $this->morphMany('Message','messageable');
}

class Chat extends Model
{
public function messages(){
    return $this->morphMany('Message','messageable');
```

These return empty.

example data used:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYzPu.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to include namespaces in my Database messageable_type.

Changed from Group to App\Group.

Answer (score 1):

You relationships are incorrect. You need to reference the full class namespace, not just the class name itself. E.g.

```
class Group extends Model
{
    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(\App\Models\Message::class', 'messageable');
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried with/without full namespacing and no difference.

Comment: What does your database schema look like, specifically for the morphable fields?